# Does it exist a fail2ban alternative in official Centos repository?

Tags: centos, ssh, fail2ban

If I don't want to add other repository (EPEL for example) than the official ones that are coming with a fresh CentOS install, is there a more official alternative than `fail2ban`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. EPEL is maintained by community around Fedora and RHEL so it is the most official source you can get `fail2ban` from.